# Is it possible to change the min-height of Google+ comment on Blogger?

Tags: css, comments, google-plus, blogger

I just created a new **Blogger blog** and successfully incorporated the **Google+ comment** using the Blogger built-in feature. But I noticed that a `div id="widget_bounds"` is consuming too much of empty spaces with the `min-height=600px` CSS property. I suspect that the code was generated on the fly and I couldn't find the `div` in my Blogger template code. I wonder if it is possible to change its `min-height` to something like `250px` and let it auto-expands as the comment grows?

You can refer my website with this URL:
http://blog.malaysiatraining.net/2013/08/official-blog-announcement.html

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to change.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

You can't to change the min-height of google+ comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem.

You can set style for frame's parent element:

```
.parent {
   position: relative;
   height: 240px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```